# jQuery Find and replace Text in iFrame Src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe with a certian text:

mytext

```
<iframe src="theURL?mytext" ... />
```

How can I search for "mytext" and remove it?

Comment: You can take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$('iframe[src*="mytext"]').attr('src', function(i, oldSrc) {
    return oldSrc.replace('mytext', '');
});
```